# Correct way to search between dates

Tags: c#, sql-server

My query must grab customers' statements and certain data between certain dates. For testing purposes, I've created a few test accounts and used the full query.

Now I need to filter between dates. This is my current query:

```
SELECT 
FechaDeSistema, 
Code, 
CASE 
    WHEN DR_Socio = @SocioNum THEN cast(Cantidad as decimal(19,2)) 
END as Debit, 
CASE 
    WHEN CR_Socio = @SocioNum THEN cast(Cantidad as decimal(19,2)) 
END AS Credit, 
CASE 
    WHEN DR_Socio = @SocioNum THEN cast(BalanceDebito as decimal(19,2)) 
    WHEN CR_Socio = @SocioNum THEN cast(BalanceCredito as decimal(19,2)) 
END AS Balance 
FROM Ledger 
 WHERE (Debito_Cuenta = @Acct) 
 OR    (Credito_Cuenta = @Ncct) 
 AND (FechaDeSistema BETWEEN @Start AND @Final)
 ORDER BY FechaDeSistema DESC";
```

The parameters for the dates are given by two calendars I have set up. However, when I generate the report, it still shows the whole range of data, never picking between the dates I chose. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What time of `DateTime` parameters are you trying to implement into your database?

Comment: The table is of DateTime data type, the parameters being passed are the from the Calendar in WPF, in this case CalendarStart.SelectedDate. Is that correct?

Comment: The WPF calendar control could be passing DateTime value in a regional format that SQL does not accept.

Comment: @LordRelix Yeah, the reason I asked is because of the reason mentioned above by jp.

Comment: Will check the value then. Thanks.

Comment: It should be in the correct format. (MM/DD/YYYY, TT:TT:TTTT)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your WHERE clause to this:

```
 WHERE (Debito_Cuenta = @Acct OR Credito_Cuenta = @Ncct) 
 AND FechaDeSistema BETWEEN @Start AND @Final
```

Your parenthesis were not correct and was grouping your clauses wrong.

Comment: Nope. Still pulled the whole range of data. I thought that might have been it too

Comment: Is the  `WHERE (Debito_Cuenta = @Acct OR Credito_Cuenta = @Ncct)` part of the clause working?

Comment: Following daughtkom suggestion it worked. Yours was lacking the parenthesis between fechadesistema and @final. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

It's probably an order of operations issue on your WEHRE clause.

```
WHERE something
    OR somethingelse
    AND onemorething
```

SQL is probably interpreting those differently than you expect.  Add parentheses somewhere to clarify what you actually need.

Comment: Oh darn, that was it. Wow. Thanks a million!

Comment: Yup. Somehow the initial parentheses flew over my head.